# Bootstrap & CSS - Text incorrectly aligns with radio button when there is a word wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

So, can't seem to figure out why this is happening. The text inside a `<span>` correctly aligns to the right of the radio button when there isn't a word wrap. If there is a word wrap, the entire `<span>` is situated underneath the radio button, including the first line. See picture below:

[image]

The first radio button text is aligned correctly.

[image]

Text without a word wrap aligns correctly.

HTML:

```
 <div class='checkbox'>
   <input type='radio' id='statementbody' class='statementselector pull-left' "/>
   <label for='statementbody'>  <span>TEXT HERE</span> </label> </div>
```

CSS 'pull-left' is part of Bootstrap:

```
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
```

I should also add that I cannot eliminate the `<label for>` and `<span>` tags.

Comment: Looks like a `vertical-align` issue to me.

Comment: @Paulie_D As in, I should add a `vertical-align` property?

Comment: Probably but without seeing it in action, it's hard to be certain. Try `vertical-align:top` on the input and label.

Comment: @Paulie_D Unfortunately, that did not fix it. Doesn't seem like anything changed.

Comment: Then it's time for a demo of this not working...

Comment: @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/skylit/q3gn0ozo/1/ Although it isn't necessarily replicating the problem I have... the fiddle's issue now is that it's wrapping underneath the radio button..